# Rails passing HTML as JSON and then rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

is there a way to pass HTML in a JSON object with Rails so you can render the the JSON object as HTML, versus as a string. meaning not seeing the text

but there actually being a paragraph tag/html style.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work

`render :json => render_to_string(normal_options_for_render)`

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to dynamically inject HTML content via a JSON responses or return JSON data with HTML content?

If you're looking to include structured JSON-like data with HTML to be rendered, you should consider using HTML data attributes like so:

```
<ul id="vegetable-seeds">
  <li data-spacing="10cm" data-sowing-time="March to June">Carrots</li>
  <li data-spacing="30cm" data-sowing-time="February to March">Celery</li>
  <li data-spacing="3cm" data-sowing-time="March to September">Radishes</li>
</ul>
```

If you're trying to return HTML markup inside your JSON, you can embed the HTML as a string object and re-ify it into the DOM during processing:

```
{
  'foo': 'bar',
  'html': '<p>some markup to be rendered</p>'
}
```